# User add text to shapes

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

How can I provide to user the ability to add or change a text inside a shape e.g. circle.

Let's say I have the following snippet, how to add text when the user clicks on the circle and writes something:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c1');
var circle = new fabric.Circle({radius: 30, fill: '#f55', top: 100, left: 100});

canvas.selectionColor = 'rgba(0,255,0,0.3)';
canvas.selectionBorderColor = 'red';
canvas.selectionLineWidth = 5;
canvas.add(circle);
```

I found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10009080/interactive-text-fields-with-fabricjs) about that but the problem is that I want the user to add text in every shape in the canvas.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [the question you found's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10062031/904263) and just do a little bit of modifying.

You will first have to figure out where the user clicked on the canvas and see what field text is there. To do that look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5023867/904263) and [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9WWqG/2/).

```
function collides(rects, x, y) {
    var isCollision = false;
    for (var i = 0, len = rects.length; i < len; i++) {
        var left = rects[i].x, right = rects[i].x+rects[i].w;
        var top = rects[i].y, bottom = rects[i].y+rects[i].h;
        if (right >= x
            && left <= x
            && bottom >= y
            && top <= y) {
            isCollision = rects[i];
        }
    }
    return isCollision;
}
```

Once you know what text field has been clicked on, you can edit that field.